# Should answers like these be deleted on this site?

Tags: discussion

Answer to this question [What is the black stone in the Kaaba?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/what-is-the-black-stone-in-the-kaaba) was deleted by one of the moderator. The answer is clearly non Islamic but the contents has some level of research and the author does seem to make some valid points (at least it seems).

Obviously this answer  may most likely offend Muslims (I am assuming) but it may have some truth in it. So Should offensive answers be accepted on this site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the censorship?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/791/why-the-censorship)

Comment: @Islam this is discussion and about the scope of the site. I would someone to clarify if they have clear views.

Answer (score 5):

The answer posted far from being "Islamic" it was offensive which you yourself assert in your question. All the The SE sites won't accept offensive answers.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think it's fair to say that this answer is "clearly non Islamic"; it's definitely opposed to *mainstream* Islam, yes, but it *does* represent beliefs held by many who identify as Muslim (particularly, but I doubt exclusively, Qur'an-only Muslims).

Such a post would be just as welcome as any other post, which is to say that it would still need to be judged according to the quality, relevance and respect it presents.  The same criteria by which any other post would (or would not) be deleted would apply.

The same would apply to any (hypothetical) posts which *are* "clearly non Islamic," but I question what if any relevance they would ever have on an Islam Q&A site.

Comment: In this post the author at least made some points which *could* be valid. Do you think it should have not been deleted? or it was better deleted?

Comment: @Ifoundthetruth It was deleted for being offensive, not for being off-topic.